# Can't send email using Spring and Quartz

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring,Quartz to schedule send email function.But I can't do that
This is my error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTr ansport.java:557)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderIm pl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:382)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderIm pl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:291)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderIm pl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:277)
at org.vnitt.service.SendMailService.sendMail(SendMai lService.java:59)
at org.vnitt.shedule.SendMailJob.executeInternal(Send MailJob.java:47)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBea n.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:90)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:2 02)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run (SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

---And here is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailS enderImpl">
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/> 
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="465" />
<property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
<property name="username" value="myemail@gmail.com"/>
<property name="password" value="mypass"/>
<property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
<prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>


<bean id="mailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" >
<property name="from" value="myemail@gmail.com" />
<property name="subject" value="Testing send email using Spring and Gmail " />
</bean>



<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.Sched ulerFactoryBean">
<property name="triggers">
<list>
<ref bean="cronSendMailTrigger"/>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- end config Quartz to schdule a task -->

<!-- begin config to schedule SendMailService -->
<bean id="sendMailService"
class="org.service.SendMailService">

<property name="mailSender">
<ref bean="mailSender"/>
</property>

<property name="mailMessage">
<ref bean="mailMessage"/>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- config JobDetail -->
<bean id="sendMailJob"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDe tailBean">
<property name="jobClass">
<value>org.shedule.SendMailJob</value>
</property>
<property name="jobDataAsMap">
<map>
<entry key="sendMailService">
<ref bean="sendMailService"/>
</entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- config cron trigger -->
<bean id="cronSendMailTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronT riggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail">
<ref bean="sendMailJob"/>
</property>
<property name="cronExpression">
<value>0 0/1 * * * ?</value>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- end config to schedule SendMailService -->
<bean id="urlMapping"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.Sim pleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<props>
<prop key="/spring_quartz_scheduler.vnitt">mainController</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.Intern alResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass">
<value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlVi ew</value>
</property>
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>


</beans>
```

Plz help me to solve this problem!
Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answer. I have fix my bug, I did not set recipient in my code and my configuration.That's cause.

Comment: Which version of Spring and Java mail you are using?

Comment: Can you tell, what is happening in org.shedule.SendMailJob?

Answer (score 10):

Are you specifying recipients for your email message? You're not doing so in Spring context (`to` is not set). That's most likely the reason for NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced the similar kind of issue and its due to no recipients.